# enable or disable csrf_protection for a bundle

Tags: symfony

Symfony2 propse to enable or disable csrf_protection for framework, for example:

```
    csrf_protection: 
        enabled: false
```

or
        csrf_protection: false

we should notice the two configuration is totally diffrent, the first one means the csrf is loaded but is false, the senconde one we do not even load this functionality. well, we can easily enable it for a special form, example:

```
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
            'data_class' => 'xxx\Entity\Company',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
    );
}
```

in a form builder class.

But i do not think it is enough, so i ask this question, could we do something like :

```
mybundle:
    csrf_protection:
        enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can globally disable csrf_protection in your `config.yml` file for every bundle in your project, but I don't think it's possible to do it for just one of your bundles.

Instead, you will need to modify the options array on every Form class of that bundle, like this:

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class'      => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
            'csrf_protection' => false
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```